# Understanding an OpenVPN bridge from iptable's point of view

Tags: linux, iptables, vpn, openvpn, bridge

In my scenario, there is a machine which acts as both an iptables-based firewall and an OpenVPN-server at the same time. It has two network interfaces - `eth1` is connected to the internet whereas `eth0` is connected to the LAN behind the machine.

Until now, I understand how to configure iptables for **routing/TUN**-based VPN-connections. You can find the following visualization on openvpn.net:

```
|            FIREWALL            |
|                                |
{eth1                        eth0}
|   \                        /   |
|    +----------------------+    |
|    | iptables and         |    |
|    | routing engine       |    |
|    +--+----------------+--+    |
|       |                |       |
|     (openvpn)-------{tun0}     |
|                    10.8.0.1    |
+--------------------------------+
```

According to the image, the logical paket flow looks like this:

Internet --> eth1 --> iptables (via INPUT-chain) --> OpenVPN --> tun0 --> iptables (via FORWARD-chain) --> eth0 --> LAN

...which should result in the follwing iptables rules if I'm not wrong:

```
# allow incoming and outgoing VPN traffic from/to the internet
iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -p udp --dport 1194 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth1 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
# allow traffic between tun0 and LAN
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun+ -o eth0 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun+ -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

---

So far, so good. What I want to do now is to realize the exact same scenario as above but with **bridge/TAP**-based VPN connections, but I have problems understanding the logical paket flow and creating iptables rules in a bridged environment.

What I get till now:

- `tun0` gets replaced by `tap0`
- I need a bridge-interface between eth0 and tap0, let's call it `br0`

For the sake of simplicity, let's assume that both tap0 and br0 are already configured.

What I don't get is the paket flow from iptables' point of view and especially how iptables deals with `br0`. My aim is to create the same visualization and rules as above, but for the described bridged/TAP-based environment.

edit: I don't have to create a real and production-ready environment, don't worry. I just want to understand it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as iptables is concerned, br0 can be treated as a single interface (e.g. you can match `-i br0` or `-o br0`, which will apply to packets arriving on, or leaving through, tap0 as well as eth0), but you can also reference its subinterfaces in rules using the `physdev` module, e.g. `-m physdev --physdev-in tap0`.

Please try to make your question more specific and I'll try to answer it better.